# Why are these comments in a mysql file blowing up?

Tags: mysql

On the Linux command line I call this script via the mysql terminal using source...

```
--First insert new template types

insert into TemplateType(id,name,size)
        values (10,'Feature Sheet','8.5x11 ss');
insert into TemplateType(id,name,size)
        values (11,'Feature Sheet','8.5x11 ds');
insert into TemplateType(id,name,size)
        values (12,'Feature Sheet','11x17');
```

When I do I get an error saying my sql syntax is invalid.  Is this not the correct way to comment an sql file?

Comment: Why not put /* */ around `/* First insert new template types */`? Instead of --?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need whitespace after the -- or use a # instead....

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html